# Use jquery in IE9 downloaded more than 2G file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery program to download >2G files. It can work only in chrome and firefox browse, IE9 only can download <2G files.

Any way to support all browsers, or lift IE9 limit.

```
      $(this).attr('src',url)
```

$(this) is use iframe!

```
      <iframe id="iFrame" style="display: none"></iframe>

      var url = "/path/"+dl_path;
      $('#iFrame').attr('src', url);
```

**Update** 
If more than 2G, Content-Length is zero, all browsers are same.
But firefox does not know the size, also can continue to download over 2G files.
chrome can download 3G file,But the size is incorrect!

I'm use lighttpd!How to respond to the correct Content-Length to client side!

thanks!

Comment: is there any error in IE ? which server stack you are using ? php, asp.net, rails ?

Comment: you are using which server stack for this image file?

Comment: No error,download more than 2G will become oKbytes,no use php or asp.net,only to jquery url="/path/filename"

Comment: What sort of element does _this_ refer to in your code sample?

Comment: well your code syntax is correct. Edit your question with all code you had used for.

Comment: @SunishthaSingh - Yes, I'm quite familiar with that concept, but that has nothing to do with my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a bug in IE9.It doesn't have any such limit. The limits are 4GB for upload and 17TB for download. You can have more information on this [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx) page.

Comment: +1 to your answer, that is what want to answer. Wasn't that sure as new comer to jQuery.

Comment: I think that IE9 is good, because I try to the other http download more than 2G is normal.

Comment: @user1933513 Dump  IE9, it has a lot of bugs...just google and you will come to know...it is hell for jquery developers...

Comment: So there is no answer?if i use jquery?

Comment: for other browsers, you can do as you are doing....but the only thing with IE 9 is to wait for the bug fix...

Comment: I am very confused!Because I also can not find the answer!